# Numpy.nanstd not skipping nan values correctly for DataFrame read in through excel

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, standard-deviation

I have an [excel file](https://gofile.io/d/5BW2On) called 'nan_test.xlsx'
Which looks like this (the original has blanks but when printed in python the blanks are replaced with 'NaN':

```
    ID  Month1  Month2  Month3
0  ABC     1.0               
1  FFF     2.0     2.0     2.0
2  XYZ             3.0     3.0
```

I am trying to get standard deviation while ignoring blank/nan values.

As of now I have this but the behavior is all over the place. It correctly does std dev for the row with 3 numeric values, 2 numeric values and one nan value, but not the one with 2 nan values and one numeric value.

```
df = pd.read_excel('nan_test.xlsx')
print(df)
df['std'] = np.nanstd(df.iloc[:, 1:], axis=1, ddof=1)
print(df)

    ID  Month1  Month2  Month3
0  ABC     1.0     NaN     NaN
1  FFF     2.0     2.0     2.0
2  XYZ     NaN     3.0     3.0
    ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  std
0  ABC     1.0     NaN     NaN  NaN
1  FFF     2.0     2.0     2.0  0.0
2  XYZ     NaN     3.0     3.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `ddof=1` causing first row `std` returning `NaN`.

```
ddof : int, optional

Means Delta Degrees of Freedom. The divisor used in calculations is N - ddof, 
where N represents the number of non-NaN elements. By default ddof is zero.
```

So, `N` of first row is `1` (i.e. there is only 1 non-NaN value). `N - ddof = 1 - 1 = 0`. Divisor is `0`, so `std` returns `NaN`

You need `ddof=0` to have the first row

```
df['std'] = np.nanstd(df.iloc[:, 1:], axis=1, ddof=0)

Out[416]:
    ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  std
0  ABC     1.0     NaN     NaN  0.0
1  FFF     2.0     2.0     2.0  0.0
2  XYZ     NaN     3.0     3.0  0.0
```

Comment: I am trying to mirror the values of STDEV given by excel. Doing STDEV of 1 and 2 in excel gives 0.7. Doing np.nanstd of 1 and 2 with ddof=1 also gives 0.7. But if I set ddof=0 then I get 0.5 I see there's some more wonky math stuff happening so I'll dig into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are setting the delta degrees of freedom (`ddof`) to 1. As it states in the docs for [`np.nanstd`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html):

> The divisor used in calculations is N - ddof, where N represents the number of non-NaN elements. By default ddof is zero.

So by setting that to 1, when you only have 1 value that is not a NaN, the divisor becomes 0, and you get a NaN.

If you change to set `ddof=0`, then you get a value of 0 for the stadard deviation of the first row